# Is there a schema.org structure for earthquake data?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

Is there a structure I can use for earthquake data in schema.org?

```
- location
- magnitude
- latitude
- longitude
- date
```

I found lat,lon in : schema/**Place** that can be used, but it's not enough!

Comment: You don't need to find some structured data to apply for SEO.  Unless there is a relevant structured data for which Google supports a rich snippet, there is no reason to use any structured data at all.  See [SEO Myth: Structured data helps search engine rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/structured-data-seo/)

Comment: Mh interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no specific schema.org type for earthquake data.

I looked at the `Event` schema, and it looks like it's entirely geared towards social events, not natural events.

And the `Place` schema doesn't cover an earthquake either, because an earthquake is a Thing that happens at a Place, it's not a Place in itself.

The most specific type you could use, in my opinion, is `Thing`.

I see that your question is tagged [seo](/questions/tagged/seo). If you're looking to add structured data for SEO reasons, as Stephen mentioned in the comments Google does not support rich snippets for this data type, so marking this up can't help your SEO.